Можно ли в webview перехватить drag&drop, начатый в Android Activity?
Собственно, вопрос в заголовке. У меня есть активити с listView, webView и ещё некоторыми view, которые в данный момент не важны.
Webview загружает заранее подготовленный html-файл с использованием javascriptinterface из папки assets. Я хочу, чтобы пользователь мог переместить элемент из listview в webview, а дальше перехватить уже посредством javascript внутри webview это перемещение и продолжить его, поскольку внутри html у меня тоже своя структура из div'ов, в один из которых пользователь должен перетащить элемент.
Вопрос в том, что я не знаю, возможно ли такое реализовать. Я знаю, как реализуется drag&drop в android java. Я знаю, как реализуется drag&drop в html dom javascript (второе знаю лучше, так как опыта в js больше, а java только начал изучать). А как одновременно в одном перемещении задействовать эти 2 разные технологии, я не знаю, и возможно ли это?
P. S. Поиск пока ничего не дал, одна банальная ерунда возвращается.

Так мне кто-нибудь подскажет? :)

Можете продублировать ваш вопрос на англоязычный стек, и если там получите ответ, то напишете его сюда)

Спасибо\nПопробую :)

Пока не получается, я захожу на основной домен .com, а он мне не даёт действия совершать - пишет "учётная запись с данным e-mail уже существует", хоть я и авторизован. Пробовал там имя поменять (изначально заходил через гугл аккаунт), не даёт. Дичь какая-то. Неужели разработчики stackoverflow, казалось бы, сайта для разработчиков и о разработке, не додумались сделать единый аккаунт на все свои поддомены? Там отображается другое имя профиля. Кстати, перезайти тоже пробовал - не помогает
